# Manipulate .ods (OpenOffice) file by using c#

Tags: c#, openoffice-calc

We have one existing ODS file (Open office spreadsheet)  comprise of multiple sheets. I am intending to read the data from each sheet on want to update some cells on each sheet using c#

I have googled a lot but not able to find any perfect solutions. I went through open office website also but got no success.

Can any one please name some free api or sample code

Answer (score 0):

**Alternate approach**

Open the file with Open Office, save it as an XLS or XLSX file and then use one of the Excel editing libraries out there.
Open Office should be capable of reading/writing the XLS or XLSX files.

I had no issues editing these formats with [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) so far, but there are also other libraries.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is reading now, you can manipulate ODS files as XMLs as seen [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38425/How-to-Read-and-Write-ODF-ODS-Files-OpenDocument-2). There are NuGet packages available for easier manipulation as well, but this is the bare-bones approach